# Want wireless bridge which provides POE (power over Ethernet)

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge, power-over-ethernet

I have an IP camera in my mailbox with POE. I would like to connect this camera in to my Synology router, but I only have available 3 cables in my mailbox. Is there a wireless bridge which provides POE, so I could connect it like so:

```
POE IP camera -> POE wireless bridge -> my wireless network
power         -> POE wireless bridge
```

Comment: There is no wireless camera, only poe camera (rj45 ethernet). What I would like to have is poe wireless bridge, meaning that I would power wireless bridge and wireless bridge would power camera over poe.

Comment: Wireless bridge is basically ethernet to wifi convertor.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [help/dont-ask]. Try [hardwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [Ubiquiti airGateway Installer Indoor AP](https://www.ui.com/accessories/airgateway/) (AG-PRO-INS-US) provides what you're asking for. It is available from [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/ubiquiti-ag-pro-ins-us/p/14U-007A-00010?item=9SIA9GZ3ZD9783), [Big Wide River Trading Co.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017B00ZCO), and doubtless other vendors.